# Statistical Modelling Research Papers

Tags: logistic, modeling, reporting

Good afternoon.

My task was to make a logistic regression model for a dataset to predict a binary variable (0/1). During this process I went through all of the stages of model building, from scratch given unprocessed data with missing values, which I then performed EDA on and after testing found a final model. I now need to write a report on this (about 12 pages, 3000 words), and I would like to read through some research papers to understand the layout and how they present their findings, to get an idea of how to structure my report.

Does anyone have any recommendations for any research papers, where people similarly started with raw data and went through the process of constructing a model, and presenting their findings?
Thank you.

Comment: I think that's an awesome idea. Regretfully, in the academic literature, people tend to only present the final model without much discussion of how they go there or how else they may have proceeded, so I'm not sure what I can recommend for this.

Comment: Unfortunately I agree with you, I tried doing some research myself and couldnt find anything I was looking for, only final model.